# How can I evenly auto-distribute values across 12 columns in a spreadsheet so that their sums are as close to equal as possible?

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I'm trying to distribute a bunch of annual recurring business costs across the span of 12 months so as to make each month's total expenditure as close to each other as possible. Doing this manually is ***exceedingly*** time consuming, and I've been trying to figure out a way to auto-sort these values into the relevant columns. Attached is an oversimplified sheet of some values and another image of a manually distributed table to exemplify the result I'm looking for. Tried to use Solver in Excel for this problem, but didn't get anywhere - I'm open to trying any other spreadsheet software to solve this (Numbers [where the real data currently is], Google Sheets, SmartSheet etc).

Image of base Values:
[image: Image of base Values]

Image of Distributed Values:
[image: Image of Distributed Values]

Had a colleague suggest using a python lib that has something like scipy.optimize? But I’m an absolute beginner at Python so that seems somewhat out of the question tbh

Comment: In your example data, B = 131 and this is quite close to 1524/12 = 127. How do you expect to proceed if one or more values are significantly greater than 1/12 of the total? For example, if B=480. Split the amount into several payments and spread them out over several months (suspend other payments during this time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to tell you how I solved this problem in LibreOffice Calc step by step. Since the functions used in the solution are the same for all types of spreadsheets, you can apply this approach to any available tool.

First of all, let’s transform the source data a little - what you showed in the first screenshot is not suitable. Let's make a table like this: three columns will contain the name of the Item, its cost and the number of the month to which this cost will need to be attributed.

A little to the right, starting from column E in the first line, we will write as many zeros as the number of groups we need to get. In this case we are talking about 12 months - that means there will be 12 zeros. If you needed to load 20 boxes of approximately the same weight, then there would be 20 zeros. I hope you get the idea.

Now let's start the calculations. In cell C2 we place the formula `=MATCH(MIN(E1:P1);E1:P1;0)`. This will look for the smallest value in the previous row and return its number - essentially the month number in which this payment is due, the payment from column B of the second row. In cell E2 we place the formula `=IF(COLUMN()-4=$C2;E1+$B2;E1)`. This formula will add the next payment to the column where the smallest amount has currently accumulated:
[image: Source table]

Now stretch cell E2 to the right to the end of the row of zeros (in our case, to column P).

Now stretch all the formulas down to the end of the available data. It should look something like this:
[image: Calculation result]

Select the left table and create a pivot table based on it:
[image: PivotTable maket]

You will get a result like this:
[image: Result]

Yes, instead of Jan, Feb, Mar you will see 1,2,3... But is this a big problem?

*If the result you get is less than ideal, try changing the order of the rows in the original table - for example, sort it  - and update the pivot table: (For your example data sorted in descending order, I got **131, 136, 131, 126, 121, 132. 122, 128, 127, 123, 125, 122**)*

Comment: This is better than anything I've come up with so far, thank you so much! Sorting by descending valuation order doesn't affect real world usage either. The only thing I'm trying to figure out with your method is for costs that have fixed payment months, let's say taxes aka item B must be payed in month 6 - how can I adjust the formulas to accommodate these 'locked-in/immovable' values?

Edit: Also this might be a stretch of an ask - are other recurring costs like biannual/quarterly ones that need to start on a specific month but need a hard # of months between them possible with this method?

Comment: Simply replace the formula in column C with the desired numerical value - write the number **6** in `C3` instead of `=MATCH(MIN(E2:P2);E2:P2;0)` and the payment will be placed in the right place. It is desirable that such fixed (non-calculated) payments be at the beginning of the list.
For quarterly payments, create four separate lines with the payment month directly coded. 
For biannual payments, enter the amount in column B using a formula like =IF(ISEVEN(YEAR(TODAY()));<amount>;0) (or use ISODD()) - the amount will appear in the table in even or odd years.

Comment: It will be better if you ask clarifying questions on one of the specialized forums - comments to the answer are not the best place to discuss details.